# How can I run OLAP queries using Node.js Driver for DataStax graph?

Tags: node.js, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I would like to run OLAP queries . Im using datastax node.js driver for OLTP 
queires. How can I run OLAP using node.js ?

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/nodejs-driver-for-datastax-enterprise

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to go about doing it, but the most direct route is to provide a `graphSource` of 'a' in the [`queryOptions`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/nodejs-dse/1.0/global.html#GraphQueryOptions) parameter of `executeGraph`.   The source 'a' communicates to DSE Graph to use the OLAP traversal source ([source](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/graphAnalytics/graphAnalyticsSparkGraphComputer.html)).

```js
client.executeGraph('g.V().count()', null, {graphSource: 'a'}, function (err, result) {
  // process result
});
```

Alternatively, you could define an [`ExecutionProfile`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/nodejs-dse/1.0/ExecutionProfile.html) at client initialization that can be reused to execute OLAP queries:

```js
const client = new Client({
  contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1']
  profiles: [
    new ExecutionProfile('olap', {graphOptions: {source: 'a'}})
  ]
});

client.executeGraph('g.V().count()', null, { executionProfile: 'olap' }, function (err, result) {
});
```